# Graph Modelling in neo4j for shortest path based on date/time?

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, shortest-path

I want to model a Graph to do pathfinding.

In the simplest scenario I've

Stations and Rides

So my Graph looks like this

```
Station A -> Ride -> Station B
Station B -> Ride -> station C
```

Now When I Search From A To C I could to some path searching for example with the [dijkstra algorithm](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-a-single-path).

But now the rides are date related. I thought about grouping them under date nodes For Departure and arrival like this (I would represent the date as a unix timestamp, just for better readbility it is a date below)

```
Station A -> 01/01/2016 -> Ride -> 01/01/2016 -> Station B
Station B -> 01/01/2016 -> Ride -> 01/02/2016 -> station C
```

This way I could start the lookup from the specific datenode of the start station.

**First Question:**

Is this a good idea?

**Second Question:**

There is still the time problem. So that the second ride must occur AFTER the first ride. I'm not sure how to handle this. Is there a way to do this with a cipher query?

Answer (score 1):

1) I would use this model:

```
(a:Station {title:'Station A'})-[:Ride]->
    (r:Ride { title:'Ride from A to B', 
              departure: '01/01/2016', 
              arrival: '01/01/2016'
    })
-[:Ride]->(b:Station {title:'Station B'});

(b:Station {title:'Station B'})-[:Ride]->
    (r:Ride { title:'Ride from B to C', 
              departure: '01/01/2016', 
              arrival: '01/02/2016'
    })
-[:Ride]->(c:Station {title:'Station C'})
```

2) And about query:

```
MATCH (A:Station {title:'Station A'})
MATCH (C:Station {title:'Station C'})
  WITH (A)-[:Ride*]->(C) as trips
  UNWIND trips as trip
    WITH filter( ride in nodes(trip) WHERE ride:Ride ) as rides
      WHERE size(rides) <= 3 AND
            all( 
                 i in range(0, size(rides) - 2) 
                 WHERE rides[i]['arrival'] < rides[i+1]['departure'] 
            ) 
RETURN 
  rides,
  reduce( resistance = 0, n in rides | resistance + n.resistance ) as resistance,
  ( rides[size(rides)-1]['arrival'] - rides[0]['departure'] ) as duration
ORDER BY resistance ASC, duration ASC
SKIP 0 LIMIT 5 // <== get the first five of the best routes
```

Comment: Looks promising iml try that

Comment: @BoasEnkler Added sorting by the time the entire route.

Comment: thank you. there are two more things. not sure wether it would be better to open a second post.
I would like to have only results with max. 3 rides. For this I assume I could extrend the where with   WHERE rides.length <=3 and all(... right?
. The Rides also do have an resistance. the lower the resistance the better the ride is. So I would ike to have the "best 3 rides" could you expand the query? or would it be better to open a second post?

Comment: No problem: 1) Add a comparison of route length - `size(rides) <= 3` 2) If Ride have resistance property - sum this by reduce and sort -  `reduce( resistance = 0, n in rides | resistance + n.resistance ) as resistance`.